# A Trivariate Normal Distribution with a Singular Covariance Matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance-matrix, singular-matrix

I have a very quick but subtle question.

Consider a trivariate normal vector:
\begin{align*} [V_1,V_2,V_3]'\sim N\left[0, \Sigma\right]\end{align*}

Here, if $V_3$ is a convex combination of $V_1$ and $V_2$ (e.g. $V_3=V_1+V_2$), then can we still say that $[V_1,V_2,V_3]'$ follows a trivariate normal distribution?

I think, the only difference is that covariance matrix $\Sigma$ becomes singular, so, we can still say that $[V_1,V_2,V_3]'$ follows a trivariate normal distribution with a singular covariance matrix.

But, I am not certain about that.

Comment: "$V_3 = V_1 + V_2$" is not a convex combination (probably you meant $V_3 = 0.5V_1 + 0.5V_2$).  Anyway, to your question, it could still be called a trivariate normal distribution even when the covariance matrix is positive semidefinite.  Remember one way of defining multivariate normal r.v. $X$ is through $X = AZ + b$, where $Z$ is a vector of i.i.d. standard normal r.v.s.  By this definition, you will get degenerated multivariate normal r.v.s when $A$ is not of full rank.